# Roles out of sync with user session

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you deal with the problem where you have user data in session state (HttpContext) and someone changes roles for them in the DB and now your session which is holding a list of roles is out of sync with the change in the DB?  You don't want to hit the DB every time to check roles.

How is this handled?

Comment: I have see the same on me and actually need to relogon to view the new roles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SqlCacheDependency to monitor a table with the roles. when the table changes, the cache is invalidated. You then query your cache for the roles, not the db.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Comment: you could in theory - but I dont know if theres a cache dependency provider with memcache to invalidate changed items based on some other dependency, thus the sql cache dependency (assuming you are talking memcached and not just any 'in memory cache' IE even built in Http Cache)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the change has been made within the same application, you could set a semaphore of sorts on a static property( maybe a dictionary ).  Then, in an httpmodule in the begin request event, check the property and refresh session data based on the property value.

Be sure to use a lock/monitor on the property to keep multiple threads from accessing it at the same time.

Comment: but I don't want to be checking the DB on every request hit...that would kill our server.  I probably want to do some polling every x seconds or minutes?  I'm not sure so that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: You won't have to. As Darthg8r suggests, you only refresh the data when the data actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

changes to a user's session variables have to be initiated by a user. There is no way that I know of to make it so that if a user is currently logged in, and an admin changes their role, to update their existing session (without the user either loading a new page, or beginning a new request). For roles/and authentication items, you probably do want to perform a check each time a new page is loaded for security reasons. This way if you block access the effect is immediate, and they're not keeping a session alive after you've shut off access.

a small check doing a basic select on one row of data shouldn't kill your server unless you're getting hundreds of thousands of requests to underpowered server/s